# How do I create a cron job that will commit my project changes to git on a weekly basis

Tags: git, cron, commit

I'm using git for the purposes of making a historical transcript of the changes made to my project. I understand it's not the ideal usage but it's the usage pattern I've chosen for various reasons which I won't get into for the sake of brevity.

How would I create a cron job that would commit the changes to the repository each day or week?

I'm using the latest version of git on Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
0 20 * * 0 /path_to_script
```

That will run the command specified (replace `/path_to_script'`) at 20:00 local time every Sunday. The syntax for cron jobs is fairly simple, and there's a [slick tool](http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/) that will help you create them without remembering the code positions.

In this case, the command should be a script that runs the commit for you. I think it would be easiest in your case to write a quick shell script to change to the clone directory and then run the commit. Create a file at `~/commit.sh` and put this in it (replacing `/location/of/clone`, of course)

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /location/of/clone
git-commit -m "commit message, to avoid being prompted interactively"
```

Then `chmod +x ~/commit.sh` to make it executable, and have the cron job run that (referring to it by it's full path, rather than using `~`).

Comment: Good answer. Keep in mind that the cronjob (obviously) only gets executed if your computer is running at the specified time (e.g. Sunday 20:00).

Comment: how can i make it do the push to the server as well?

Comment: Also, how do i make it add files that i've added

Comment: Just add git-push to the script to have it push to the server as well. You can use the -a option to git-commit to have it automatically add all files that have been modified or deleted.

Comment: Don't you want to add a `-a` to the commit command, so it will add automatically all the files that are already tracked to the staging area?

Comment: Yeah, this won't do anything without the `-a`. In addition it won't even do the commit because it is `git-commit`. I am going to fix it.

Comment: `git-commit: command not found`

Answer (score 6):

Run `crontab -e` to edit your user cronjob, and insert this line:

```
0 20 * * 0 (cd /path/to/myproject && git add . && git commit -m "Automatic Commit" && git push)
```

Of course you will have to setup your GIT repo including a working remote repository, but that's not in scope of this question.