# How to auto commit to my git repository using cron?

Tags: linux, bash, script, git, cron

I look into a lot of answers [about this subject](https://superuser.com/questions/264710/how-do-i-create-a-cron-job-that-will-commit-my-project-changes-to-git-on-a-weekl), but something is wrong here, let me explain.
I create this script, to make my `cron` cleaner :)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/valter.silva/Development/git/valter/ 
/usr/bin/git add -A 
/usr/bin/git commit -am "update `date`"
/usr/bin/git push
```

Then add it at my cron, `valter.silva's cron`, **not** my `root cron`:

```
00 * * * * /home/valter.silva/Development/git/valter/scripts/git/sync.sh
```

Restart my cron

```
sudo service cron restart
cron stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 6047
```

Aaand .. nothing happens..

But if I execute my script in command line, everything works fine.
I know for a fact that sometimes if you don't put the whole path at cron scripts won't work correctly. And that I should use my cron to do that, not root's cron.

So what's wrong here ?
Any ideas ? Thank you!

**udpate**

I follow Terdon suggestion, into log the operation, but it seems everything is okay, but not the `push` process though. Why ?

```
[master ad5d001] update Fri Aug  9 11:00:01 BRT 2013
 9 files changed, 1224 insertions(+), 364 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 scripts/centreon/4.answers~
 create mode 100644 scripts/centreon/6.importing database
 create mode 100644 scripts/centreon/6.importing database~
 create mode 100755 scripts/centreon/7.upgrade.sh
 create mode 100755 scripts/centreon/7.upgrade.sh~
 create mode 100644 scripts/centreon/8.answers
 create mode 100644 scripts/centreon/8.answers~
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: How did you add this to your user's crontab (you should use `crontab -e`)? What does `crontab -l` report? You can try to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` and `MAILTO="valter.silva"` into your user's crontab. Especially the latter might give you some error messages in your local mail (`/var/spool/mail/valter.silva`) if local mail system is working. And IMHO there is no need to restart the `cron` service.

Comment: `crontab -e`, not `sudo crontab -e`. The `crontab -l` is exactly that entry that I post it, there's only this entry in my cron.

Comment: Is the remote git server protected by an ssh key with a password by any chance ?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? Arrived here by googling. Wondering if you ever fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

To add up, I have simplified the links, so it is more readable for someone looking for an answer based on [huti's blog post](http://withr.me/git-commit-regularly-to-gitlab/).

So for your `sync.sh` I would add `-u origin master` for the push:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/valter/git-project/
/usr/bin/git add -A 
/usr/bin/git commit -am "Daily update"
/usr/bin/git push -u origin master
```

Make sure you script can be executed by bash:

```
sudo chmod 765 ~/sync.sh
```

Then you can add a line to the `/etc/crontab`:

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab # To edit the file
01 18  *  *  * root  /home/valter/sync.sh
```

Be sure to reboot for the cron job to take effect, Now your script will be run every day at 18:01. If there is no modification, nothing will be pushed though.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an git master, but I make some git tests on my local git test repo. When I run git push, then output is:

```
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

git push <name>
```

Q: Have you configured remote repository using `git remote add` command? If yes, try run git push with name of remote repository. If no, configure one, or use git push with remote repository url on command line (`git push git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/` ).

Comment: I did configure with `git remote add`, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect something to happen? You have told `cron` to run your script every hour, on the hour. If you modified your crontab at, say, 13:02 nothing is going to happen until 14:00.

Try waiting a while, until the time hits `XX:00`, your script should run. Oh, and there is no need to restart `cron`, it will read the new crontab and run it next time it should be run.

If you have waited long enough and your script is still not being run, try redirecting the error output to check if anything is happening:

```
00 * * * * /home/valter.silva/Development/git/valter/scripts/git/sync.sh 2> /home/valter.silva/error.txt
```

Also try setting up a dummy cron job to see if that works:

```
00 * * * * date > /home/valter.silva/date.txt
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this over a week now, trying to figure out what is happening to not commit my changes.

Comment: @ValterHenrique see updated answer for a couple of suggestions.

Comment: Ok, terdon, will do that. I'm cloning my repo in a different computer now :)

Comment: I update my post, could you please take a look ?